# Can I resize the VHDX of the running host Windows 8.1 of my system?

Tags: windows-8.1, vhd

I can install Windows 8.1 on a VHDX as primary system, for instance by following the steps at [Installing a Fresh Windows OS to a New Bootable VHD with no Host OS for Boot to VHD](http://www.johnpapa.net/bootoffmetal/).

That way, you are more flexible choosing the physical drive (HDD or SDD) that everything runs on. Eventually when switching to bigger drives, probably the VHDX also needs to grow.

So: Is it possible to resize this VHDX while that primary Windows 8.1 is running?

**Edit:** a picture about my configuration to make things more clear.

```
+---SSD;NTFS;D:(System,PageFile,Active,Primary)-------------------------+
|                                                                       |
| C:\Win81Ent.vhdx                                                      |
| +---NTFS;C:(Boot,Active,CrashDump,Primary)----+                       |
| | Windows 8.1 installation                    |                       |
| +---------------------------------------------+                       |
|                                                                       |
| C:\DATA (directory to backup, and to access from the outside world)   |
|                                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Questions:

- Can I resize the VHDX file from the Windows 8.1 partition that uses this VHDX file as its partition?
- If so: which tools, and how to use them?

Comment: Of course there is and it's a well documented process too

Comment: I tried to find it, but couldn't. If you have any links, please share them. The best link I managed to find until now seems not applicable to my situation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2014/01/28/online-vhdx-resize-in-windows-server-2012-r2-windows-8-1.aspx

Comment: The simplest way is to covert it to VHD use the tool of your choice then covert it back to VHDX

Comment: @Ramhound that's what my question is about, so lets make it more clear: which is the tool I should choose, and how should I use that tool?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848535.aspx also supports vhdx.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However I cannot find in that page content that this method works when the primary system uses that VHDX. Can it? Can't it? That's the information I'm after. I know that it can on a physical system (resize the HD or partition), but can it also on a VHDX?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13725/discussion-between-jeroen-wiert-pluimers-and-ramhound)

Comment: I can't join you in chat at this time;  The tool I provided can't modify the file if its in use.  But it still can be used if you have access to a dedecated vhdx image for the purpose of expanding the vhdx used for the system itself.  As I indicate after you modify the file you still have to expand the partition.

Answer (score 0):

As per [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/731076/can-i-resize-the-vhdx-of-the-running-host-windows-8-1-of-my-system?noredirect=1#comment938490_731076) from user [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound):

You cannot do this from the system running inside the VHDX, but you can do this from another Windows 8.1/2012 instance that has exclusive access to the VHDX file.

To resize from outside the VHDX, use tools like these:

- The [Microsoft Resize-VHD Hyper-V CmdLet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848535.aspx).
- [`DiskMgmt.msc` on Windows 8.1 / Windows Server 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2014/01/28/online-vhdx-resize-in-windows-server-2012-r2-windows-8-1.aspx).

After that, increase the partition using something like `diskmgmt.msc`.